# ALB with HTTP2 configuration on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http2, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to set up an Elastic Beanstalk applciatoin using HTTP2. To do this, I have created an ALB.

Target group:

[image]

Weird thing is that even I have setup the load balancer as shared in the Beanstalk configuration, an additional listener has been created:

[image]

This is the listner of the ALB:

[image]

That's the one being used by the environment, but I do not know how to change it back to the correct one. Any idea?

The instances never reach a healthy state. I'm starting my node application (using the fully managed solution) like this: `.listen(PORT)` where `PORT` is an environment variable set by AWS. It usually is 8080, in case it helps.